# ASP.net GridView: get LinkItem's row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I want to show "Delete" link in GridView to *registred users*, therefore I am using templateField:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView_Sort">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onClick="deleteEntry()"  Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now in my deleteEntry() function how can I know anything about the row in which "Delete" link was clicked? How to ge for e.g. rowindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this slightly different. You see, when a control is placed **inside** a gridview, any event raised from that control raises also the `RowCommand` on the GridView.

To get what you want you could then add both `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` to your `LinkButton` and then catch it in the GridView's RowCommand.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" commandName="LinkButtonClicked" commandArgument='Eval("myObjectID")' />
```

where `myObjectID` is the name of the ID column of your object you bind the grid to.

Then

```
void GridView1_RowCommand( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.CommandName == "LinkButtonClicked" )
    {
        string id = e.CommandArgument; // this is the ID of the clicked item
    }
}
```