# How to reference a linkbutton thats inside a asp:grid when its clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have a ASP:grid which has a link button, i need to some how reference that on the code behind when its clicked but im struggling on the syntax

Heres my ASP:Grid i need to execute code in the code behind when that link button 'Re-Take' is pressed and also be able to know what row it was clicked on as i will need to reference the users emails and name and then send an email with the relevant information....

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdViewUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
                    EnableViewState="false" class="tablesorter">
    <AlternatingRowStyle></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Re-Take" runat="server" ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperFullName" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("UserID","/ExamPaper.aspx?uid={0}") %>'
                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.FullName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Email") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exam Taken">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ExamTaken") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Taken">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DateTaken") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exam Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ExamTotal") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If someone can help me with a snippet i would highly appreciate it

Comment: No just help with referencing the click event of the link button i have done the code for the email etc

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this slightly different. You see, when a control is placed inside a gridview, any event raised from that control raises also the RowCommand on the GridView.

To get what you want you could then add both CommandName and CommandArgument to your LinkButton and then catch it in the GridView's RowCommand.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" commandName="LinkButtonClicked" commandArgument='Eval("myObjectID")' />
```

where myObjectID is the name of the ID column of your object you bind the grid to.

Then

```
void GridView1_RowCommand( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.CommandName == "LinkButtonClicked" )
    {
        string id = e.CommandArgument; // this is the ID of the clicked item
    }
}
```

see: [ASP.net GridView: get LinkItem's row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655305/asp-net-gridview-get-linkitems-row)

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` should work in this case.

```
protected void GrdViewUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink myHyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("Edit") as HyperLink;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the snippet, is there not a click event similar to how you would do a normal click event for a button?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the grid has linkbutton on which we want to get row index

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnAdd " runat="server" CommandName="cmdAdd" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.gif" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

In code behind, In OnRowCreated event we attach row number of grid to each button of row to get it back when it is clicked in RowCommand event

```
    protected void gvListing_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
          System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lnkbtnAdd = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();    
                lnkbtnAdd = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkbtnAdd");                    
                if (lnkbtnAdd != null)
                    lnkbtnAdd .CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
         }          
    }
```

In RowCommand event we will get back the current row index and set the selected index of the grid

```
protected void gvListing_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{      
   if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "cmdAdd")
   { 
       int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());// Current row

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You have repeating ID's in your TemplateFields like `lblUsername` what is not allowed since it's the same [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx).

You can pass the `RowIndex` as `CommandArgument` to `RowCommand`:

on aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton 
           Text="Re-Take" 
           runat="server" 
           ID="Edit" 
           CommandName="Edit"
           CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Handle the GridView's `RowCommand`:

```
  void GrdViewUsers_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="Edit")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);      
        GridViewRow row = GrdViewUsers.Rows[index];
        // now you can get all of your controls like:
        Label lblSurname = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSurname");
        String email = lblSurname.Text // you noticed that DataItem.Email is bound to lblSurname?
    }
  }
```

Comment: iv done the above but when i click on the link button the page just flashes and doesnt go in to the grdviewuser_rowcommand code behind?

Comment: Iv add onrowcommand="GrdViewUsers_RowCommand in the asp:grid i then added CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">
do i need to change anything in that? as im not 100% sure, i then added the GridViews RowCommand snippet in my code behind, when i run and put a break point in the code nothing is hit the page just refreshes........

Comment: @ScottAtkinson: It should work if you've added the rowcommand handler on the gridview markup(as you've said above). Are you databinding the GridView in page load on postbacks? You should do that only if `!Page.IsPostback`.

Comment: when the page loads for the first time it gets binded, but the code you have given me when i put a break point inside that well on the if(e.commandname == "Edit") it doesnt hit it this is what i have in my page load protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BuildGrids();
            }
        } the builddgrids is where i databind the grdViewUSers but again stepping through the page load event it goes in and then thats it?

Comment: @Scott: No, nothing wrong as far as I can tell. I don't know why RowCommand isn't fired. Does it work if you handle the LinkButton's click event instead? You get the GridViewRow reference there via `var row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;`

Comment: Hm, ill have a play around with it and see whats actually going wrong